# React-grid-Layout with Redux and Hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-grid-layout

I am a beginner in React and I have a problem with react-grid-layout,
Indeed I create an action in my reducer to reset the placement of my cards in my grid. The parameters stored in "props" change as I wish but the visual rendering does not take into account the new parameters, here is my code:

```
const DashboardGrid = (props) => {
    let [content, setContent] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        setContent(CreateContent(props));
    }, [props.newGrid])
    function CreateContent(props) {
        let dash = props.newGrid
        content = dash.map((_c, _i) => {
            if (dash[_i].isVisible === true) {
                return (
                    <div className='case' key={_i} cti={_i} data-grid={dash[_i].dataGrid}>
                        <Card id={_i} />
                    </div>
                )
            }
        })
        return content
    }
    function restore() {
        props.restoreGrid()
    }
    CreateContent(props)
    return (
        <GridLayout  className="layout" cols={props.cols} rowHeight={props.rowHeight} width={props.width}>
            <div key="title" data-grid={props.dashboards.dataGridTitle} className="dashTitle">{props.dashboards.title}</div>
                <div onClick={restore}>
                    <Icon type="undo" />
                    &nbsp;Restaurer la grille
                </div>
            {content}
        </GridLayout>
    )
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        newGrid: state.async.dashboards[0].dashboard,
        dashboards: state.async.dashboards[0]
    }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        restoreGrid: () => dispatch(cardAction.restoreGrid()),
    }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DashboardGrid)
```

My reducer sends me good coordinates in my props, but the components of my grid do not change. Please tell me or I am wrong or if there is a possibility to force the calculation of components.

Comment: Maybe I use the useState badly? I think that the parameters of the cards are not interpreted when rendering the second time

Comment: I found a solution, I assigned a key to each component and I iterait each action on my grid, so the components whose key is iterated are destroyed and rebuilt by React taking into account the accessories.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I assigned a key to each component and I iterait each action on my grid, so the components whose key is iterated are destroyed and rebuilt by React taking into account the accessories.